# Why do they use >, <, and == in compare(float float1, float float2) in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point, compare

I know the typical way to compare floating point number where the solution is to check not whether the numbers are exactly the same, but whether their difference is very small:

```
float a = 0.15 + 0.15;
float b = 0.1 + 0.2;
if( Math.abs(a - b) < 0.00001)
    // The numbers are considered equal
```

I copied the example above [from here.](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/)

And now I don't understand why it's correct to compare two float variables this way:

```
public static int compare(float float1, float float2) {
    // Non-zero, non-NaN checking.
    if (float1 > float2) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (float2 > float1) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (float1 == float2 && 0.0f != float1) {
        return 0;
    }

    // NaNs are equal to other NaNs and larger than any other float
    if (isNaN(float1)) {
        if (isNaN(float2)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    } else if (isNaN(float2)) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Deal with +0.0 and -0.0
    int f1 = floatToRawIntBits(float1);
    int f2 = floatToRawIntBits(float2);
    // The below expression is equivalent to:
    // (f1 == f2) ? 0 : (f1 < f2) ? -1 : 1
    // because f1 and f2 are either 0 or Integer.MIN_VALUE
    return (f1 >> 31) - (f2 >> 31);
}
```

That's from the source code of [Float.compare(float f1, float f2).](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare(float,%20float))

Comment: `float` is a promitive type. The code is not using the object `Float`!

Comment: 1) to implement `compare()` in some way; 2) if you compare using epsilon, how you will know before, which value is suitable for all cases? Which exactly piece does bother you?

Comment: It's incorrect to implement `compare()` in the other way you described.

Comment: @tmyklebu, do you mean if( Math.abs(a - b) < 0.00001)? Yes, I know it's incorrect because the values themselves can very small so that using 0.00001 is incorrect. Or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comparing floats with == is not "incorrect". It just might produce confusing results for someone not familiar with floating point numbers.

In most real word scenarios == has the desired behavior. Usually, you do not care that the numbers are "almost" equal. You want perfect equality, because you are checking some corner case.

`Float.compare` primarily defines an order not equality. Bigger numbers should always be after smaller - no matter how small the difference. You don't want to end up with sorted array: `[0.000002, 0.000001, 0.000003]`. Otherwise, most algorithms (for example binary search) would produce garbage results.

In cases where you want equality within a limit, the limit is some defined property like line width, brush thickness or hit box size. In such cases you have to compare the difference against that property rather than hardcoded epsilon. It might have sense to have `Float.compare(a,b,epsilon)` method. It's just not very useful.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is between business code and "absolute" code.

In business code floating point equality is usually expressed in the way you described, so that 1.000000001 and 1.000000002 can be considered equal (if it makes sense in the business logic).

However since the `compare` method is just comparing two floats and has no idea whether 1.001 and 1.002 should be considered same or not, it does a purely raw calculation (as well as considering the special cases such as `NaN`).

Answer (score 0):

Java tries to achieve some performances gains by checking if float1 > float2, etc.- First 3 if blocks. It gets rid of usual suspects, so to say. Say I want to compare 10.5f and 12.2f, the if checks at the start of compare methods does achieve better performance by returning correct results quite early on. It does not have to go to the length of check whether it is NaN or comparing the bits. This is sort of low hanging fruit (wow... 'low hanging fruit' and 'usual suspect' in a single answer :))

Then, because the client code which uses java compare may want to compare the two numbers in sufficient details, java uses the bitwise operators.

For normal comparisons a few decimal point difference may be acceptable. But it may not be so for ALL applications that rely on java.

Answer (score -1):

The Java Compare-Methods and the `java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(T)`-Method works just like that:

```
@return  a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this 
         object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.
```

With the Compare-Method, there are three possible return-values: greater then, less than and equal. With a `boolean` you can only cover two states, thats why they use a integer return type.

So that compare-Method of Float must check the absolute value,  even small differences are threated as non-equal (grater or lesser).